# tbl_svysummary by two variables

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am having the following dataframe

```
data <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25), 
                       strata = c(10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 20, 10, 20, 30, 30, 10, 30, 30, 20, 10, 20, 20, 20, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 20, 30), 
                       weight = c(10, 8, 17, 15, 9, 10, 25, 8, 8, 13, 17, 24, 12, 15, 3, 12, 16, 17, 24, 12, 3, 2, 8, 14, 4), 
                       popgroup = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                       gender = c("Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male"),
                       inc_01 = c(1500, 1200, 130, 500, 750, 2000, 10000, 1500, 1050, 400, 360, 490, 250, 400, 2500, 1300, 800, 540, 690, 520, 600, 700, 700, 600, 400), 
                       inc_02 = c(360, 450, 120, 300, 900, 560, 450, 280, 720, 360, 1000, 900, 530, 820, 640, 520, 130, 140, 150, 650, 240, 130, 200, 300, 500)), 
                  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -25L))
```

and am interested in performing an analysis by a combination of two variables. I found the inspiration [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70572643/is-possible-to-do-a-table-with-two-group-by-with-tbl-summary-in-r)

The code am using is below

```
table_01 <- data %>%
  as_survey_design(strata = strata, weights = weight) %>%
  select(popgroup, gender, inc_01, inc_02) %>%
  filter( !is.na(popgroup)) %>%
  tbl_strata(
    strata = gender,
    ~.x %>%
      gtsummary::tbl_svysummary(
        by = popgroup,
        type = list(inc_01 ~ "continuous",
                    inc_02 ~ "continuous"), 
        statistic = list(c(inc_01, inc_02) ~ "{mean} ({mean.std.error})"),
        missing = "no",
        digits = list(c(inc_01, inc_02) ~ c(4, 4)),
      ) |>
      gtsummary::add_p(
        test       = all_continuous() ~ "svy.t.test",
        pvalue_fun = function(x) gtsummary::style_pvalue(x, digits = 3)
      ) |>
      
      gtsummary::modify_fmt_fun(
        update = statistic ~ function(x) gtsummary::style_number(x, digits = 6)
      )
  )
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!